# Matlab Figure Visibility

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a Matlab function which when runs, somehow, the 'visible' property of ALL the figures in matlab is turned off. For example, if I type

```
figure
```

nothing happens....but if I type this

```
figure('visible','on')
```

a blank figure is displyed normally. This situation remains till I restart Matlab. My question is, Is there a way to turn this'universal Visibility' back on????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-21465.html) how to set default properties for figures and axes. Basically, the format is

```
set(0, 'default[some property here]');
```

to set session-wide default values. Note that you can get a list of some of the default parameters you can set with

```
get(0, 'default')
get(0, 'defaultfigure')
get(0, 'defaultaxes')
```

Note also that NOT all user-settable parameters are shown, and that such a list is actually pretty hard to find (I could not find it...)

Anyway, I suspect what you're after is

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'on');
```